# What happens if I delete a member, does it delete their entries?

Tags: members

I have a couple of members of a site that have recently left the company. If I delete the members will this also remove all entries that were created/edited by them? I want to keep anything they would have entered into the system.

Using an older version of EE v2.5.2 with Multiple Site Manager

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete a member, ExpressionEngine presents you with the option to either delete all of their entries, or reassign them all to a different member.

Comment: perfect, that's exactly what I want, cheers