# How do I delete users without deleting their content?

Tags: delete

I need to delete users from an ExpressionEngine site, version 2.7.2. How do I do it without deleting their respective entries and content?

This question might be a duplicate - [What happens if I delete a member, does it delete their entries?](https://expressionengine.stackexchange.com/questions/30095/what-happens-if-i-delete-a-member-does-it-delete-their-entries) - but I don't have the reassign option. I only get a warning:

```
Are you sure you want to delete these members?

guest_user
THIS ACTION CANNOT BE UNDONE
```

[image: Member delete warning]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe it only gives you the option to reassign if they actually have content. At least thats what I thought? Maybe it just looks at the users channel posting priviledges before offering the re-assign option...

Has guest_user actually posted anything yet??

Another option is to create another member group based on "banned" or "guest" and instead of deleting a user move them in to your new sand-boxed group...

Comment: Just noticed some activity on this very old answer, just thought I'd chime back in and mention that with the new GDPR standard rolling out you need to make sure you manage the "sand boxed" data now. As its linked to a user it's likely personally identifyable so you're responsable for storing and deleting that content after time.

Answer (score 1):

You could just change their member information to whatever you wish.
If one of the goals of deleting their account is to remove access to the EE CMS, changing them to a lower-level member could do it. Also, you could create a new member group and assign them to it -- something like "legacy authors" and then you can change the permissions for the group. The benefit of this method is that it would allow you to keep them in the author dropdown in the CMS -- and the next time you need to do this, that group is already set up.